# How to use FirebaseAuth's verifyPasswordResetCode(); method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I am trying FirebaseAuth and I'm using version 10.0.0 in my gradle. Tell me the use of the method like

`verifyPasswordResetCode();`

`confirmPasswordReset();`

I have tried like this but its not working.

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.verifyPasswordResetCode("somecode");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the common use of password reset is to send link via email that points to reset password web page. So your Android application should only trigger to sent that email only. Verification process and password reset take place in web browser.

To do so, you should read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email

But if you want to do verification and password reset in your Android app, then this answer is irrelevant.